# Tomcat 7 failing to load class due to unsupported class version exception, but java version seems correct (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, tomcat7, version, ubuntu-12.04, java-7

I'm chasing a mystery issue and could use an extra pair of eyes.. I must be missing something!

I have an war application that is built with source level 1.7. When I deploy it to a Tomcat 7 running on Ubuntu x64, I get an exception in the logs:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/develop-status.war
Jan 1, 2014 11:14:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/develop-status]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/specktro/orchid/deployment/monitor/DeploymentMonitorServletContextListener : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.specktro.orchid.deployment.monitor.DeploymentMonitorServletContextListener)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2840)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1668)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClassAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:381)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 37 more
```

I thought this was very straightforward: Tomcat must be running with a lower java version than the one used to compile the war.

Then I check the java version on the machine used to compile, and it matches exactly the version on the machine running tomcat:

```
administrator@ci-server:~$ java  -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

administrator@ci-server:~$ /etc/alternatives/java  -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

administrator@ci-server:~$ javac  -version
javac 1.7.0_25

administrator@ci-server:~$ /etc/alternatives/javac  -version
javac 1.7.0_25
```

I also checked that Tomcat is being started with the correct java version:

```
administrator@test-websites:~$ /etc/alternatives/java -version

java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
administrator@test-websites:~$ /usr/share/tomcat7/catalina.sh version
bash: /usr/share/tomcat7/catalina.sh: No such file or directory
administrator@test-websites:~$ /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh version
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Server built:   Apr 1 2013 08:32:04
Server number:  7.0.26.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.8.0-34-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_25-b30
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

JAVA_HOME seems to be set correctly:

```
administrator@ci-server:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

**UPDATE:**
Then I added the following to catalina.sh

```
  echo "JAVA_HOME:"
  echo $JAVA_HOME
  echo "JRE_HOME:"
  echo $JRE_HOME
  echo "java -version"
  java -version
```

And got a correct output:

```
administrator@test-websites:~$ sudo /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh start
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/lib/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/lib/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
JAVA_HOME:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
JRE_HOME:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Then I tried Oracle's JDK 7 instead of Open JDK. I installed  Oracle's Java 7 on both the machine which compiles the classes and the one which runs tomcat:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

I got the same results...

**Does anyone have a clue on why would I be getting this error message?**

I don't know where to look anymore, any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"Thank you!!!

Eduardo"*  Noise.  Please leave it out of questions.

Comment: print out java version from  inside catalina.sh back it up first. was it edited before?

Comment: Hi @tgkprog ! thanks for replying. I added the info you asked to an update in the question. Please let me know if you'd like more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue!
Despite setting the environment variable JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment or exporting it, one must also change the /etc/default/tomcat7 file to use the correct JDK.

So do:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's|#JAVA_HOME=.*|JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"|' /etc/default/tomcat7
```

This will uncomment the JAVA_HOME line on that file and set it to Oracle's Java 7. If you use a different JDK, update the line to match yours.

That's it! Now tomcat can load my servlet just fine.

Thanks everyone who contributed to this research!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using open JDK in your ubuntu. Try to replace that with Oracle JDK. I faced a lot of problems with Open JDK. Here you have a [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux) how to do it.

I don't know will it help but at least you may give it a try.

Comment: That didn't work.. I'm using Oracle's Java 7 now and still I get the same error...

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon this issue too when trying to get it to use the Oracle JDK. Changing the link of "default-java" did it for me:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/<your jdk here> /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

I did not investigate further but i think it gets detected somewhere in the shell script and overrides environment variables.

Comment: Cool, I'm trying right now and will let you know

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it, I'm still getting the same issue...